# To make the text in a text view so that it cant be copied

Tags: iphone, uitextview

HI All,

I need to display some text in text view, but i want no one should be able to copy/change it while reading that text.
I have already set _TextView.editable=FALSE where _TextView is the object of the text field, but still it gives the option to the user to copy the text.

Also at the end of the text I want to give a URL and want it to display it in blue & underlined and if user click on this text part then it will connect him to the mentioned web page.

How can I do this.

Please help me.

Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe you could beginning by setting good answers of your questions in your profil before asking another question ?

Comment: Sure, will do that next time, but now pls help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part if you set User Interaction Enabled to off then they won't have the option to copy the text.

This will however make any "detected" URL un-clickable.

I think it might end up being a choice of either or in this case.

Hope this helps, M.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `UITextView` and override `canPerformAction:withSender:`

```
@interface MyTextView : UITextView {

}

@implementation MyTextView

-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(cut:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

@end
```

To enable clickable links set `textView.dataDetectorTypes` to  `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.